# Como podria ordenar datos de un archivo con muchos datos

Tags: c++, archivo, csv

Tengo un archivo que contiene los viajes entre las distintas estaciones de una ciudad con el numero de cada parada en una columna de un archivo *.csv* del cual se sacar esos numeros pero al ser 100 estaciones y querer ordenarlas por uso significa que debo de tener todos los valores asignados a una estacion y realizar primero los conteos de cada estacion para luego almacenarlos localmente y ordenarlos para luego relacionar el numero con el nombre de la estacion que tengo en otro archivo e imprimir todo ello a un *.txt*

¿Alguna idea de como realizar la ordenacion de esos datos?

El archivo donde se encuentran los datos es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar estructuras de datos. Una posibilidad es leer todo el CSV y almacenarlo en una lista. Una vez tienes eso ordenas la lista como te de la gana y vuelves a guardar los datos.

Las [estructuras de datos](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/) son algo básico:

```
struct Item
{
  int id_usuario;
  std::string retiro_dt;
  int retiro_estacion;
  std::string anclaje_dt;
  int anclaje_estacion;
  // ...
};
```

Y para la lista de elementos puedes usar [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Item> listado;
```